# How can I open a chrome tab on my laptop from my react-native app (like remote debugging does)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a small debugging app to monitor a particular interaction (WebRTC) between two users of my main app.

I have a web app (React) and a mobile app (React-Native) that each connect through socket.io to a node server I created. This node server's purpose is to collect information from both users, and display this information in a web page in real time.

My web app has a button that when you click it it opens up that debugging web page in a new tab with the debugging information; I just use `window.open`. **Is it possible to do something similar from my mobile device, running a react-native application? That is, can I click a button and have a browser tab open on my laptop somehow? Does React-Native remote debugging work with something like this?**

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no supported way you can do this in React Native.

However, you can certainly add it yourself.

Navigate to `node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/getDevToolsMiddleware.js`

Look for `launchChrome(debuggerURL);`, you can invoke another `launchChrome` function with your desired URL.

This will only appear when you select `Debug JS Remotely`.

You can configure the CLI server code more to launch the URL when you are **not** debugging.